# Regex to find a file in folder

Tags: c#, .net, regex

How to find all files matches a regex pattern in a folder?

Thanks

Comment: +1 This is a short and direct question and i think it was deserved to get point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) method allows you to specify a wildcard pattern but not really a regex. Another possibility is to simply loop through the files and validate their name against a regex.

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\somePath")
    .Where(name => Regex.IsMatch(name, "SOME REGEX"));
```

Comment: The `Directory.EnumerateFiles` was a great addition to .NET 4.0 as it returns `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `string[]` meaning that unless you start enumerating it won't block.

Comment: btw, `Directory.EnumerateFiles` is a .NET 3.5 feature

Comment: @abatishchev, no it isn't, checkout the doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx

Comment: @abatishchev: Read that document more closely. Specifically the Version Information part which says "Supported in: 4".

Answer (score 0):

Regex matching of filesystem is not supported
you will have to iterate through each of the files in the directory and check them individually