# How to find files in a folder in an ASP.NET application using C#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have created an Asp.net application.

It contains a folder called PDF and a folder called Requirement just beneath that.

I have a link in another page called Requirement.

If i click on that link i need to find all the files in the folder PDF/Requirement.

Comment: Do you know `System.IO.File` and `System.IO.Directory`?

Comment: You can google for this and get your answer in under 1 minute.

Comment: I get only string "/pdf/Requirement". I need to append application path along with above. How can i do that ?

Comment: I tried Request.ApplicationPath. But return only root application Folder name, not all path where that folder exists ?

Comment: i got answer Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.

Comment: You can use Server.MapPath("~/pdf/requirement") to get the full path. Tilda char means get the path relative to the application root (which might not coincide with the website's root, since in a website you can have other applications)

Comment: In the future, please breakup your questions into sub-questions, recursively as needed, so that you eventually end up with *specific*, *concrete* problems. As-is, you've clarified that you really had several problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var getFileName = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/PDF/Requirement"));  // Collection Of file name with extention.

var getFileNameExcludeSomeExtension1 = from f in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/PDF/Requirement"))
                                       where Path.GetExtension(f) != ".scc" && Path.GetExtension(f) != ".db"
                                       select Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f);   // Collection Of file name with extention and filtering.

var getFileNameExcludeSomeExtension2 = from f in Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/PDF/Requirement"))
                                       where Path.GetExtension(f) != ".scc" && Path.GetExtension(f) != ".db"
                                       select Path.GetFileName(f);   // Collection Of file name with out extention and filtering.
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use EnumerateFiles as this  [Regex to find a file in folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554559/regex-to-find-a-file-in-folder) and if you tried GetFiles dont because of performance you could see difference in this [What is the difference between Directory.EnumerateFiles vs Directory.GetFiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669617/what-is-the-difference-between-directory-enumeratefiles-vs-directory-getfiles)