# What is the difference between Directory.EnumerateFiles vs Directory.GetFiles?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, io

What is the difference between `Directory.EnumerateFiles` vs `GetFiles`?

Obviously one returns an array and the other return Enumerable.

Anything else?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles#System_IO_Directory_EnumerateFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_):

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

So basically, `EnumerateFiles` returns an `IEnumerable` which can be lazily evaluated somewhat, whereas `GetFiles` returns a `string[]` which has to be fully populated before it can return.

Comment: Lazy evaluation may not come for completely free - for example if you will be putting it back to an array in the end (I saw that!). Lazy is efficient when "yagni"-all: you are not going to need all elements, and just stop iterating after a few.

Comment: Lazy enumeration is also interesting if you're going to enumerate a so large collection that building the whole collection first in memory is too heavy. You can just process the items as they come and forget them.

Comment: @TomaszGandor: Or when there's no need to store all filenames, e.g. when just renaming files.

Comment: I looked into the sources and found that both methods use internal `FileSystemEnumerableFactory.CreateFileInfoIterator()`. But `EnumerateFiles()` returns this iterator directly while `GetFiles()` builds extra `List` from it and calls `ToArray()`. So, if you care of speed it makes sense to use `EnumerateFiles()` and to deal with the iterator yourself.

Comment: Another good example is when you actually don't care about any of the files, and you just want to check if the folder has any files or empty. In that case you can simply use `Directory.EnumerateFiles(path).Any()`, which will return immediately after the first file and almost as fast as when the folder is empty.

Answer (score 38):

`EnumerateFiles` returns `IEnumerable<string>` and that implies deferred execution. It is only available in .net 4 and up.

As the File system is notoriously slow (especially for large folders) the deferred execution can be a real bonus for sequential processing.  Depending on lots of other factors.

Comment: There is nothing called ".net 4".  Back in 2011 there was only .NET Framework so that was not so unclear. But today there is a thing called just ".NET" and so this is now unclear.

Answer (score 19):

When using EnumerateFiles, all speed is lost if you are then using `.Last`.  This makes sense of course, because to get to the last file, it will need to enumerate all files, then grab the last one.

However, using `.First` or `.FirstOrDefault` becomes very fast, because it simply grabs the first item and moves on.

Comment: This very old question asked what differences there were apart from the `Array` vs `Enumerable` aspect. Your answer is generic to all such situations but does not answer the question asked.

Comment: The point is, EnumerateFiles lets you start accessing data quicker, in some cases.

Comment: The point is, this is very useful as a comment but it doesn't answer the question. There is a distinction.