# How would I return top FileInfo object with the oldest date time?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to be able to query a local directory for the files that I add to it. The method that contains the LINQ Query will return the file whose create date is the oldest. So, the order of operation is basically a First-In First-Out scenario.

Note that I am returning a list because the requirements may change to return more than one file.

The code I've come up with to achieve most of this is as follows:

```
public static List<FileInfo> GetNextFileToProcess(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    var files = from f in directory.GetFiles()
                orderby f.CreationTime ascending
                select f;

    return files.Cast<FileInfo>().ToList();
}
```

The problem is that I have not limited this list to containing and returning only the file whose index is 0 after determining the sort order.

Do I need a where clause to limit the oldest file from being returned or what?

Comment: @JonSkeet Because my returned object is a List and an IEnumerable is not a list and so needs to be cast to one to return it.

Comment: That's why you're calling `ToList()`, but `Cast()` still just returns `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet AH! Thank you! I didn't change that code as before I was returning out a custom object. Damn. See, shotgunning code bites you in the butt always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var files = (from f in directory.EnumerateFiles()
             orderby f.CreationTime ascending
             select f).Take(1);
```

Comment: I didn't know you could "group" an entire Linq statement like that with parens.

Comment: you'd want `EnumerateFiles()` in this case

Comment: @BrokenGlass: Why? There will be no result before all files are retrieved anyway.

Comment: You would need twice the memory otherwise though, once for the array returned by `GetFiles()`, and once for the collection created by `OrderBy()`

Comment: @BrokenGlass Okay, I'll change it to `EnumerateFiles()`.

Comment: Related: [Directory EnumerateFiles vs GetFiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669617/directory-enumeratefiles-vs-getfiles)

Answer (score 2):

You've said you want to return a list in case you need more than one file later on - so why bother limiting it? You *could* use `Take(1)`, but why not just return everything to the caller and let *them* decide what they want?

If you're going to limit it to "a list containing one element" you might as well make it just return a `FileInfo` instead - you'll need to modify the code if you want to return more than one entry anyway.

Comment: This is true. I am dealing with some rolling requirements at the moment that will likely change by the time I have my meeting on Friday.

Comment: @Tomalak True, but there has been talk of processing two files at a time, so in that case I would need the two oldest files from the directory. I just wanted to see how I could handle this with a list moreover.

Comment: @fullNelson: Do you even need to return a `List` rather than an `IEnumerable<FileInfo>`? If you just return the files in order, then the caller can decide whether to call `Take(1)` or `Take(2)`...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thats a good idea. Shaping it downstream would be a better option.

Comment: @fullNelson I concur with that. While my answer may have solved your immediate problem, Jon's is the better solution.