# Directory.GetFiles sort by date

Tags: sorting, date

I am using Directory.GetFiles to get files from a particular folder.
By default files from that folder are coming sort by filename ie. in alphabetical order of filename. I want to get files in the order in which files are modified.

I cannot use Directory.GetInfo as I want to get the files which contain particular keyword.
Please let me know how can we get the file sorted by their modified date.
I am using the following code

```
string[] arr1 = Directory.GetFiles("D:/TestFolder", "*"Test12"*");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 20):

what about the below

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\TestFolder");
FileSystemInfo[] files = di.GetFileSystemInfos();
var orderedFiles = files.Where(f=>f.Name.StartsWith("Test12"))
                        .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
                        .ToList();
```

you can replace `f.Name.StartWith` with any string function against your need (`.Contains`,etc)

you can replace `f => f.CreationTime` with  `f.LastWriteTime` to get the modified time but bear in mind that starting in Windows Vista, **last access time is not updated by default**. This is to improve file system performance

Comment: How to write this in VB files.OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)

Answer (score 18):

if you change to directory info you could do

```
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo("path")
                        .GetFiles("filter")
                        .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
                        .ToArray();
```

**Edit:**
Saw you wanted modified date, can do that with f.LastWriteTime instead

Comment: Also consider `EnumerateFiles` rather than `GetFiles`.

Comment: @mjwills i wonder why?

Comment: @waseemrakab Read the docs to see why one might be preferred to the other. Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669617/what-is-the-difference-between-directory-enumeratefiles-vs-directory-getfiles .

Comment: perfect! and `.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)` is what I actually needed. Thanks for the starting place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. It will work...

```
            string path = "C:\\Users", FileName="YourFileName";
            DirectoryInfo direct= new DirectoryInfo(path);
            FileInfo[] files = direct.GetFiles();
            Array.Sort(files , (x, y) => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(x.CreationTime, y.CreationTime));
            files = Array.FindAll(files , a => a.FullName.Contains(FileName) == true);
            foreach(var file in files){
                // do what you want.. 
                Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post, but if what you want to get is an array of string, you'll probably need to execute a select at the end.

```
string[] myFiles = new DirectoryInfo(@"folder\path").GetFiles("*.txt").OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTime).ThenBy(f => f.Name).Select(f => f.FullName).ToArray();
```

The above line returns all the .txt files in the directory, sorted first by modification date and then by name, as a string array.

I hope it helps someone.