# C# - How to recursively search a directory in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, search, directory

I can do this task in a normal form application but i am brand new to working with WPF applications.

I want to enter a directory path in a `TextBox`, then click a `Button` which validates and recursively searches that path, and displays all the files in a `ListBox`.

I have already looked at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974) article but i don't understand it fully because again, i'm very new to this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What don't you understand from the link you linked ? The example there is 5 lines if we exclude the try catch.

Comment: FYI, searching directory recursively doesn't have anything to do with WPF. This is base C#.

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("your path");
dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Use `EnumerateFiles` for efficiency: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669617/what-is-the-difference-between-directory-enumeratefiles-vs-directory-getfiles

Answer (score 1):

Or this;

```
void DirSearch(string sDir) 
{
    try 
    {
       foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
       {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text)) 
        {
           lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f);
        }
        DirSearch(d);
       }
    }
    catch (System.Exception excpt) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: so i place this in but what code do i put in the search button event handler?

Comment: +1. @user2189007 - you asked question about making recursive search. If you really needed something else (which seem to be the case based on this comment) - please ask separate question with exact task you have problem with.