# How to search for a SINGLE file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, file, directory

I want to search a directory and its subdirectories for a single file.

The directory tree is very large and i don't want to search all the directory tree , but just search to the first found file.

Currently I have tried the following:

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
"myFile.ext",
SearchOption.AllDirectories);

myFileInfo = new FileInfo(files.First());
```

the problem with the code above is that it search all the directory tree.

my main focus in finding the file is **performance**.

Comment: You may have to write your own iterator of directories using DirectoryInfo and not search with the AllDirectories option to get the option you are looking for.

Comment: What's wrong with this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx ?

Comment: Did you measure actual performance of EnumerateFiles before searching for better solution?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Your code will *not* traverse all files - it *is* an enumerator which means you can get the first result before the entire tree gets traversed. Actually, if you used [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343(v=vs.110).aspx) you'd get back a FileInfo directly, no need to get the path first, then create a FileInfo

Comment: This is the fastest method you could find, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5669635/1155650) for difference.

Answer (score 1):

What you have tried is indeed the solution. It does not loop through all your directory tree but a part of it; until the file is found.

Alternatively - as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364663/how-to-search-for-a-single-file-in-c-sharp#comment54524663_33364663) -, you can get [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8) class directly (if necessary):

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .EnumerateFiles("myFile.ext", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String searchFile(String searchPath, String fileName)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(searchPath);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        if (file.Name.Equals(fileName))
            return searchPath;
    }

    foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in dirs)
    {
        String value = searchFile(Path.Combine(searchPath, subDir.Name), fileName);
        if (value != null)
            return value;
    }
    return null;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String searchPath = @"C:\PathHere";
    String searchFile = "log.txt";

    String foundFileAt = this.searchFile(searchPath, searchFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public string FindFirstFile(string dir, string file)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, file)))
    {
        return Path.Combine(dir, file);
    }
    foreach (var subDir in System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir))
    {
        var result = FindFirstFile(subDir, file);
        if (result != null)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var topDirectory = @"D:\top directory";
var file = "foo.txt";
var theFile = FindFirstFile(topDirectory, file);
```

It's more complex than the build in functionality, but you get more control over when when you return.