# Can't get file with Directory.get files c#

Tags: c#, file, directory, getfiles

I want to get my specific files with `Directory.GetFiles` but i can't

```
var deleteFile = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\").Where(f => f.Contains(lastBackup.DbName + " DiffBackup.bak")).ToList();
                
                    foreach (var file in deleteFile )
                    {
                        File.Delete(file);
                    }
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? Do you get an exception? Is the `deleteFile` list emtpy? Can you specify a filename that actually exists in the "C:\test\" directory you expect to find with this code? It's really hard to help you without additional information.

Comment: You've told us you "can't" but you haven't explained why not. The code looks fine to me. You also haven't actually asked us a question. What is going wrong? And what help do you need?

Comment: I am sorry. I'm new here. When i run my code i get the `deleteFile` list empty. I wrote again and it's fixed. I don't know how. I just wrote. I did not change my form or app. I don't know what to do now. Should i delete my question?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\test\", lastBackup.DbName + " DiffBackup.bak").ToList();
```

This will look in the directory for all files with a certain extension, for example:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\test\", "*.*").ToList();
```

This would return all files found in said folder.

Comment: The `ToList` call [makes the enumaration pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5669635/2590375) and since that is the only difference, i doubt that it solves the problem.

Comment: You are correct, however from his example I thought `List<string>` output since it might be more workable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your path is invalid.

Try to use Path.combine() to get a good Path -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0

And test if your path is correct with Directory.Exist() or File.Exist if it's a file.

Comment: Thanks i am looking.