# Directory.EnumerateFiles: How to specify a range or a list as searchPattern

Tags: c#, .net

Given a list of files like this:

```
file_1.txt
file_2.txt
file_3.txt
file_4.txt
file_5.txt
file_6.txt
```

How do I invoke `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` to get a range or a list of files? For example

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "file_*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

would return all the six files above, and so far so good. But what if I want to get a range (i.e. from `file_3.txt` to `file_5.txt`) or a list (i.e. `file_1.txt`, `file_4.txt` and `file_6.txt`)?

What I'm looking for is something like this (the code here below doesn't work... it is just to give you an idea):

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "file_{3-5}.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

to get a range of files

```
file_3.txt
file_4.txt
file_5.txt
```

... and then

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "file_{1,4,6}.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

to get an exact list of files

```
file_1.txt
file_4.txt
file_6.txt
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on DavidH's answer.

Use LINQ and System.Text.Regular expressions to get the file list:

```
IEnumerable<string> files1to3 =  Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\", "File*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, "File[1-3].txt"));
IEnumerable<string> files4to6 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\", "File*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, "File[4,5,6].txt"));
```

In response to @j3d:

```
IEnumerable<string> files150to200 = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\", "File*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(f => Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(f, @"\d+").Value) >= 150 && Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(f, @"\d+").Value) <= 200);
```

For lists of file numbers you could do something like this:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList searchArrayList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
searchArrayList.Add(new int[] { 1, 125, 1554 });

foreach (int[] i in searchArrayList) {
    IEnumerable<string> findFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c:\", "File*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(f => i.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(f, @"\d+").Value)));
}
```

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4734164/1967692)

Comment: No need to call ToList(), EnumerateFiles returns an IEnumerable that can be used with Where  as  is

Comment: Thanks! I have removed the ToList() call.

Comment: Just a comment... File[1-3]\.txt just works for numbers less than 10... what if I need to match file names like File333.txt? In other words, I need to specify any kind of range (e.g. File[150-200]\.txt)

Comment: OK, ranges work fine... and what about lists? How do I filter file names like File1.txt, File125.txt, or File1554.txt? I've tried .Where(f =>Regex.IsMatch(f, @"(1|125|1554)")); ... but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your support! Really appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

Directory.EnumerateFiles seems to only work with simple wildcards.  However, according to this question/answer ([How to find files according RegEx in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809604/how-to-find-files-according-regex-in-c-sharp)).  You could use LINQ and a regex match to do the filtering instead?

Answer (score 1):

Combine it with LINQ:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "file_*.txt").Skip(2).Take(3);

Directory.EnumerateFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "file_*.txt").Where(...);
```