# Constructing a C# RegEx for any given filename

Tags: c#, .net, regex, filenames

Question for any RegEx masters out there who have a minute to help me out... I have an application which allows users to specify a filename which is used to grab files off of an ftp or local directory... In the filename, they are allowed to specify wildcards using the * character...

Examples include:

```
file1*.txt, *.* , acb*.* , file.txt , *abc*.xml , filewithnoext*
```

I need a dynamic regular expression to filter my file list and only retrieve files based on the users input... Can anyone out there help me with this? Thanks for taking the time to take a look.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve file name without extension?

Comment: yes if no "." is present in the user input text

Comment: Can you show us the code used to retrieve the files? Perhaps the input by the user, including the wildcards, could be used by the function retrieving the files...

Comment: [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443524/using-directory-getfiles-with-a-regex-in-c) is very close to what you want

Comment: The wildcard is essentially an subset of Regular Expressions, you can just take their string, escape special characters like `.` and replace the wild card with a .*? which will match anything 0 or more times but as few as possible

Comment: currently, they specify the filepath and I take that to construct the Regular expression... I have:  Regex regexFilter = new Regex(
                    "^" + Regex.Escape(Path.GetFileName(strLocaFilePath)).Replace(@"\*", ".*").
                       Replace(@"\?", ".") + "$",
                       RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); But this is incomplete. I need it to work for examples like (wildcard).(wildcard)

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
string reg = Regex.Escape(userinput).Replace(@"\*", ".*?");
```

Then iterate through each file and check them by doing something like this:

```
foreach (string file in files)
{
    if(!Regex.Match(file + "$", reg).Success)
        continue;

    //...
}
```

Comment: The input can also contain a `.` so you need to replace that too

Comment: @T.Kiley It'll be escaped via `Regex.Escape()`

Comment: @FrancoTrombetta it should, *.* would turn into a Regex match for `.*?\..*?` but you should definitely look at Jonesy's comment on the OP which has a link to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443524/using-directory-getfiles-with-a-regex-in-c

Comment: You'll want to add `$` to the end of the regex. Otherwise "*.xml" will match "myfile.xml.txt" and "myfile.xmltest".