# Sort part of a list in descending order (by date), the other part in ascending order (alphabetically)?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a control which shows a list of all PDFs in a selected folder. The names of most of these PDFs (for example, meeting minutes) begin with a date. I want these PDFs shown in descending order so that the most recent PDFs are shown at the top.

In the same folder I also have some PDFs whose names do *not* contain a date (for example, policies). I want these files to be ordered alphabetically.

Here is an example of the kind of list I have and how I want it to be ordered:

- 2019-01-12 Meeting minutes.pdf
- 2018-11-19 Meeting agenda.pdf
- 2018-06-02 Meeting minutes.pdf
- 2017-12-13 Meeting agenda.pdf
- 2017-04-27 Meeting minutes.pdf
- Privacy policy.pdf
- Safeguarding policy.pdf
- Welfare policy.pdf

And here is what I have tried:

```
private void GenerateFolder()
{
    folder_path = Server.MapPath(BaseFolder);
    _folder_view = new StringBuilder();

    if (Directory.Exists(folder_path))
    {
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(folder_path);
        FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(p => p.FullName).ToArray();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        { 
            doStuff();
        }
    }

    folder_view.Text = _folder_view.ToString();
}
```

With this code, the PDFs whose names begin with a date are ordered in descending order (by date) which is what I want. But the other PDFs whose names do *not* begin with a date are not ordered the way I would like (alphabetically). Is there a way to accomplish my dual-sorting objective?

Comment: You need to us OrderByDescending using Date along with Full Name.  So use ThenByDescending.

Comment: Perhaps using this regex solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443524/using-directory-getfiles-with-a-regex-in-c  , you could generate two partial lists which you would then combine.

Comment: The canonical way to do this would be to write a custom [`IComparer<string>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer?view=netframework-4.7.2) that implements your custom sorting logic.  You can then pass that in to the proper overload of [`OrderBy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_OrderBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Collections_Generic_IComparer___1__).  That may be inefficient though, because of having to constantly...

Comment: ...A more performant solution would be to parse the filenames in to a custom class, breaking apart the date and the name, implementing an `IComparer` on *that*.

Comment: `.OrderByDescending(...).ThenBy(...);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a custom class that parses out the date and the rest of the filename in to separate properties, you can then use `OrderByDescending` and `ThenBy` to sort on these individual properties.

```
public class ParsedFilename
{
    public ParsedFilename(string filename)
    {
        FullName = filename;
        if (filename.Length >= 12 &&
            DateTime.TryParse(filename.Substring(0, 10), out var date))
        {
            Date = date;
            Name = filename.Substring(11);
        }
        else
        {
            Date = null;
            Name = filename;
        }
    }

    public DateTime? Date { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string FullName { get; }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var data = new List<string>(new[]
    {
        "2019-01-12 Meeting minutes.pdf",
        "Safeguarding policy.pdf",
        "2017-04-27 Meeting minutes.pdf",
        "2018-06-02 Meeting minutes.pdf",
        "2017-12-13 Meeting agenda.pdf",
        "Privacy policy.pdf",
        "Welfare policy.pdf",
        "2018-11-19 Meeting agenda.pdf"
    });

var parsedData = data.Select(d => new ParsedFilename(d));

var sortedData = parsedData.OrderByDescending(d => d.Date)
                           .ThenBy(d => d.Name);

var output = sortedData.Select(d => d.FullName);
```

It produces the following output:

> 2019-01-12 Meeting minutes.pdf
>   2018-11-19 Meeting agenda.pdf
>   2018-06-02 Meeting minutes.pdf
>   2017-12-13 Meeting agenda.pdf
>   2017-04-27 Meeting minutes.pdf
>   Privacy policy.pdf
>   Safeguarding policy.pdf
>   Welfare policy.pdf

Depending on the formats of the filenames in your directory, you may have to add some more robust parsing.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, [LocEngineer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4579015/locengineer) suggested (paraphrasing):

> Start by using a regex-based technique as shown by answers to [this
>   question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8443524/1497596) to determine those file names that begin with dates. And then
>   generate two partial lists which you would then combine.

In the spirit of that suggestion, here's a demonstration of one possible solution:

```
public void CustomFileNameOrderingDemo()
{
    var files = new[]
    {
        "2017-04-27 Meeting minutes.pdf",
        "2018-11-19 Meeting agenda.pdf",
        "2019-01-12 Meeting minutes.pdf",
        "2018-06-02 Meeting minutes.pdf",
        "2017-12-13 Meeting agenda.pdf",
        "Safeguarding policy.pdf",
        "Welfare policy.pdf",
        "Privacy policy.pdf",
    };

    var filesWithDates = FindFilesWithDates().OrderByDescending(f => f).ToList();
    var filesWithoutDates = files.Except(filesWithDates).OrderBy(f => f);
    var result = filesWithDates.Concat(filesWithoutDates);

    IEnumerable<string> FindFilesWithDates()
    {
        return files.Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, @"^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} "));
    }
}
```