# How to count the number of matches of files in a directory

Tags: c#, regex, file

I was looking many questions after answering this.

How I find if in a directory exists at least one (and better if you give me the number of) files which matches a certain regular expression?

I know I can loop the files in the directory [with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1601327/2662302)

But there is a way of counting without looping?

I try with count() but that don't work

Comment: No, you have to get the files in the list and then Match using regex pattern. The where clause will filter. Do you have large number of files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from your linked question / answer, this should work:

```
int count = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\temp").Count(path => Regex.IsMatch(path, pattern));
```

Comment: you are matching path with regex..I guess it should be `Regex.Match(File.ReadAllText(path),pattern)`

Comment: note you can also use a handy shortcut method: `Regex.Match(path, pattern).Success` can be replaced by `Regex.IsMatch(path, pattern)`, which directly returns a `bool`.

Answer (score 3):

If the pattern is simple, then GetFiles in Directory already provides the information without using RegEx.

```
int count = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get them without the bottom foreach loop by using the Length property of the array returned by the Directory.GetFiles method.

```
int count = matches.Length;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx