# C# - Getting file names starting with a specific format in a directory

Tags: c#, regex, file

I've a directory with tons of files and I want only to get the names of the ones starting with `sly_`.

If I'm not wrong, the patter for this is `^sly_`.

This is my try using the solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1601327/742269) question:

```
    string pattern = @"^sly_";
    var matches = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\mypath").Where(path => Regex.Match(path, pattern).Success);

    foreach (string file in matches)
        Console.Write(file);
```

Unfortunatelly, this doesn't list the files matching my pattern. So, can someone tell me what's wrong with me code and how can I list the file names starting with `sly_`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles("YourDirectory", "sly*")` should do.

Comment: Your regex wouldn't work because the `^` indicates for the pattern to start at the beginning of the string, I believe. So this looks for all elements returned by `GetFiles()` that also begin with `sly_`, but since your path is `D:\mypath`, none of those values start with `sly_` and you're not getting any matches. Like the two other answers posted, use `Directory.GetFiles(string path, string searchPattern)` instead. Far more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you insist on *regular expression* you should test *FileName*, not the *entire path*:

```
  string pattern = @"^sly_";

  var matches = Directory
    .GetFiles(@"D:\mypath")
    .Where(path => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(path), pattern));

  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, matches));
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to use regex at all. This is more readable and efficient:

```
string[] matches = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\mypath", "sly_*");
```

[`Directory.GetFiles Method (String, String)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx)

`*` is a wildcard for "zero or more characters in that position" and it's used only one the file-name not the full-path. If you wanted to include the extension:

```
string[] matches = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\mypath", "sly_*.txt");
```

Your regex would also work if you just use the file-name not the full-path:

```
var matches = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\mypath")
    .Where(path => Regex.Match(Path.GetFileName(path), pattern).Success);
```

But as mentioned, this is less readable and not efficient. Remember that `matches` currently is only a LINQ query, not a collection. You need to add f.e. `ToArray` to get one. Otherwise this query is executed always when you use `matches`.

Comment: while this does get him what he wants, it might also be helpful to explain why what he tried is not working for him.

Comment: "can someone tell me what's wrong with me code" - no, we'll just tell you to copy paste a different way of doing it rather than help you build off your own work

Comment: Just adding a note for the OP that the second string `searchPattern` parameter is only used for the file name itself, it doesn't include the entire path, so that's why you don't need to do `*sly_*`.

Answer (score 7):

Your *actual* issue is that [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) returns

> An array of the full names (including paths) for the files in the specified directory, or an empty array if no files are found.

You regex would need to check for the `D:\mypath` part as well as the `sly_` part. Other than that, your expression is correct.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy using Linq and classes DirectoryInfo and FileInfo. A FileInfo has properties FileName and FullFileName. Usage would be as follows:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> myFiles = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\mypath")
    .EnumerateFiles()
    .Where(fileInfo => fileInfo.Name.StartsWith("sly_", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Use Enumerable.Select to get the sequence with full file names or short file names

Answer (score 0):

Why your code is not working is, `Directory.GetFiles()` returns the full path of files, like

```
D:\mypath\sly_yourFile.txt
```

So, the string path doesn't start with `sly_` and does not match your Regex `@"^sly_"`.

A simpler solution is to provide the search pattern to `GetFiles()` method like

```
Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\mypath", "sly_*")
```