# Search file in Directory using partial name in C#

Tags: c#

I need to search file in directory using partial name.

Ex:

```
Directory : c:\Path
Filename  : Error_005296-895632-12563.xml
Partial file name: 005296-895632-12563
```

I have tried below.

```
Directory.GetFiles("c:\Path", "*005296-895632-12563*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
```

But it didn't work

Sample file names are :

```
Error_005296-895632-12563.xml
005296-895632-12563_Response.xml
Duplicate_005296-895632-12563_Response.xml
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443524/using-directory-getfiles-with-a-regex-in-c may help

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601241/c-sharp-regex-matching-file-names-according-to-a-specific-naming-pattern

Comment: You don't even need regexes or patterns, just loop over the filenames in the directory and use `string.Contains`

Comment: Answers will differ by language. Please select either c# or vb.net

Answer (score 1):

You can create a extension method and pass the array of partial names which you want to find.

Call the extension method like this

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\demo");

FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFilesBypartialName("Anc_def_", "ABC_123", "12_qweqweqw_123").ToArray();
```

below is the extension method

```
public static class DirectoryFindFile
{
    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesBypartialName(this DirectoryInfo dirInfo, params string[] partialFilenames)
    {
        if (partialFilenames == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("partialFilenames");

        var lstpartialFilenames = new HashSet<string>(partialFilenames, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        return dirInfo.EnumerateFiles()
            .Where(f => lstpartialFilenames.Contains(f.Name));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> GetFilesBypartialFilenamesAllDir(this DirectoryInfo dirInfo, params string[] partialFilenames)
    {
        if (partialFilenames == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("partialFilenames");

        var lstpartialFilenames = new HashSet<string>(partialFilenames, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        return dirInfo.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                       .Where(f => lstpartialFilenames.Contains(f.Name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres a extension function I've used to search directories

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path, string searchPatternExpression = "", SearchOption searchOption =    SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{

    Regex reSearchPattern = new Regex(searchPatternExpression);

    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", searchOption).Where(file => reSearchPattern.IsMatch(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file)));
 }
```